# How Do I get Input in a certain format in my C Program

Tags: c, input

So im trying to get input from a user in my C program.

This is the format of the input:

5

5 8 9 4 2

The user will enter the size of an array, then the user will press enter and input the elements of the array.

So my question is how do I save the first line to an int variable and the second line to a char array where i can manipulate it later?

Comment: have you tried anything at all?

Comment: Search for the `scanf` function.

Comment: search for the `malloc()` function for allocating the array given the first input

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the `scanf()` function. It's pretty self explanatory. Don't forget though that the variable that it stores in to must be a pointer so don't forget the `&` before a non-pointer variable.

Answer (score 0):

Read the size, allocate memory, read the data

```
unsigned size;
if (scanf("%u", &size) != 1) return error;
char element[size];
for (unsigned i=0; i<size; i++) {
  if (scanf("%hhd", &element[i]) != 1) return error;
}
```

Yet better to use `fgets()` and then parse the buffer.

`scanf("%u"...` scans input for 1 `unsigned` value.

`scanf("%hhd"...` scans input for 1 `signed char` value.